# NHibernate query with criteria on child collection member returns only partial child collection

Tags: nhibernate

I have a parent-child relationship between `Teacher` and `StudentReport`.  Each `StudentReport` has a timestamp field recording when the teacher finished the report.  I have a query to find all teachers who have completed one or more of their reports as of a certain number of minutes ago:

```
    public IList<Teacher> FindRecentlyActiveTeachers(int intervalMinutes)
    {
        if (intervalMinutes <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Interval must be a positive number of minutes");

        DateTime activityCutoff = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1 * intervalMinutes);

        return Session.QueryOver<Teacher>()
            .Left.JoinQueryOver<StudentReport>(t => t.StudentReports)
            .Where(r => r.FirstSaveTimestamp >= activityCutoff)
            .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
            .List<Teacher>();
    }
```

This returns the correct list of teachers, but the child collection for each teacher only contains the reports that match the selection criterion.  I would like the report collection of each matching teacher to contain all of the reports, not just the few reports that meet the criteria.

Is there some way I can either load the full child collection eagerly, or omit loading it in this query and rely on lazy loading it?

**Update**

This is the solution:

```
        return Session.QueryOver<Teacher>()
            .Fetch(t => t.StudentReports).Eager
            .JoinQueryOver<StudentReport>(t => t.StudentReports)
            .Where(r => r.FirstSaveTimestamp >= activityCutoff)
            .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
            .List<Teacher>();
```

Comment: Just a random tip unrelated to your question. To negate your intervalMinutes you can write '-intervalMinutes' and it will give you the negative value of the positive number passed in. Instead of having to do '-1 * intervalMinutes'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Fetch

```
return Session.QueryOver<Teacher>()
    .Fetch(t => t.StudentReports)
    .Where(r => r.FirstSaveTimestamp >= activityCutoff)
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
    .List<Teacher>();
```

Comment: That's it!  Thanks.  I'm still learning the QueryOver syntax, and seeing this example, I think I can clean up some of my other queries.